# Gulp watch, running multiple tasks issue

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I'm trying to setup a Gulp task that converts Sass into CSS and then minifies it.

Here's my current gulpfile.js

```
// include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp'); 
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');


//gulp sass

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./scss/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('minify-css', function() {
  return gulp.src('css/*.css')
    .pipe(minifyCss({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./scss/main.scss', ['sass','minify-css']);
});
```

I run `gulp sass:watch` and I expect it to convert `main.scss` into `main.css` which it does and then I see that it also runs `minify-css`, but it doesn't actually minify it.

If I run `gulp minify-css`, it works perfectly. Can someone please tell me how this needs to be adjusted so `gulp.watch` runs both tasks, one after another?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I got this work, by removing the additional task and combining the css minify into the sass portion.

```
// include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp'); 
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');


//gulp sass

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./scss/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(minifyCss({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

// gulp.task('minify-css', function() {
//   return gulp.src('css/*.css')
//     .pipe(minifyCss({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
//     .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
// });

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./scss/main.scss', ['sass']);
});
```